# $rootscope.$broadcast with $on

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

I have issue with Angular js
 I am calling on function with
in html 
controller

```
    <button  class="btn" ng-click="test()"> Save</button>
    <button  class="btn" ng-click="test();test2()"> New</button>

    $scope.test= function(){
       $http.put(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'api/myfile/' , {
            headers: {
                'X-ApiKey': myKey
            }
        }).success(function (data) {          

            $rootScope.$broadcast('data:saved')
            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.loading = false;               

        });
    }
```

and other function i called

```
     $scope.test2=function(){ $scope.$on('data:saved', function (event,tags) 
    {
    $http.post(settings.WebApiBaseUrl + 'api/myfile/' , {
            headers: {
                'X-ApiKey': myKey
            }
        }).success(function (data) {  

            $scope.loading = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.loading = false;               

        });
    }}
```

If i click once it work fine but i i click second time it looping second function two time.

Comment: It's very strange that you bind on to scope in a function which executes every time you click. You just need to bind it once normally and it should not be in that function

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `test2()` each time you click:

```
ng-click="test();test2()"
```

which subscribes to the event each time:

```
$scope.test2=function(){ 
    $scope.$on('data:saved', function (event,tags)
```

You only want to subscribe once, so `test2()` shouldn't be called each time you click. Just call it once, and test that `test()` broadcasts the event and is handled.

Comment: I two button is  <button  class="btn" ng-click="test();test2()"> click me</button>  button  class="btn" ng-click="test()"> TestOn</button>

Comment: It looks like the point of your `test` function is to broadcast something, that the `test2` function subscribes to. Thus you probably don't want to call `test2()` in `ng-click`. You want to call `test()`, and see if your subscription works

Comment: yes. But i have two different button. one for only one api call test and second i need both to run together thats why i use $rootscope.$broadcast. A you said its work if one function call

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but you almost certainly don't want to subscribe each time you click.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Really appreciated

Comment: I updated again I have two buttons on my html. i need both.

Comment: So you should move `$scope.$on('data:saved' ...` outside of the `test2` function, and make it call `test2`. Make sure `$scope.$on` only runs once, perhaps in the constructor or `$onInit` function of your controller.